# How do I use an url+binding in xamarin forms image tag

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'd like to put this string in an image source:

http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png
https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

But the string has to be something like:

"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/ + {Binding weather} + .png"

The problem I have is that apparently I can't use StringFormat in the label so how can I make a single line of

Other problem I have is that I don't quite understand how the binding for this works perhaps that's the whole problem, that's given from a script like:

```
    public async void GetWeather()
    {
        WeatherData weatherData = await _restService.GetWeatherData(GenerateRequestUri(Constants.OpenWeatherMapEndpoint));
        BindingContext = weatherData;
    }
```

What can I do to get the icon variable from the Weatherdata, or is there a more practical way to solve this, I still don't know very well where is that allocated or how to put that "bindingcontext" values inside c# thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working code turned out to be

```
     public async void GetWeather()
    {
        WeatherData weatherData = await _restService.GetWeatherData(GenerateRequestUri(Constants.OpenWeatherMapEndpoint));
        BindingContext = weatherData;
        temperatura.Text = Math.Round(weatherData.Main.Temperature).ToString() + " °C";
        icon.Source = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherData.Weather[0].Icon + ".png";                       
    }
```

this way I can see the icons and temperature for my query at openweather https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved but that's not data binding, which is what you were asking for originally.

Comment: I just couldn't figure out how to concatenate the string inside the xaml tag :(

Answer (score 1):

create a property called `WeatherIcon` in your `WeatherData` class and bind that as your image source

```
public string WeatherIcon
{
  get {
    return $"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{Weather[0].Icon}.png";
  }
}
```

where `weather` is the property that contains the string you need to insert into the url

Comment: It's throwing me an error the original line I use in xaml is {Binding Weather.Icon} now for some reason I don't understand I can use temperature.Text = Math.Round(weatherData.Main.Temperature).ToString() + " °C";

But I cant find the weather Icon, the class that contain that variable is public

public class Weather
    {       
        [JsonProperty("icon")]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
    }

Comment: please edit your question and add all the relevant code.  Based on your description I can't really tell what you're doing.  And "throwing an error" is not a helpful description.  Please include **specific** error messages

Comment: sorry thought of ot a bit later, the line you proposed I'm using it like; public string WeatherIcon { get { return $"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{Weather.Icon}.png"; } } can't say if I'm right, the error I'm getting is CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Weather.Icon" non static

Comment: is WeatherIcon in your WeatherData class?  Does WeatherData have a public Weather property?

Comment: If you look at the json Weather is an array.  I’m not sure what determines how many results are returned.  At this point I’m not sure what problem you’re still trying to solve?

Comment: well neither do I perhaps it was a problem with their server or something but it did worked I used beijing as a reference an voila there's a sun as an Icon, the working code indeed turned out to be: icon.Source = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherData.Weather[0].Icon + ".png"; thanks a lot for the time sometimes this bits of conversation help to find of new solutions